# How to get single row data from json response in android

Tags: android, json

Hello I am new to android,working on a snippet where I am getting my json data as

```
{"students":[{"id":"26","name":"aaa","abbr":"A"},{"id":"27","name":"bbb","abbr":"B"},{"id":"28","name":"ccc","abbr":"C"}]}
```

I want to get this record as single row, like `id=26,name="aaa",abbr="A"`

```
 JSONObject json;
 JSONArray jsonarray_student;
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
 jsonarray_student =  json.getJSONArray("students");
 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("id", json.getString("id"));
            map.put("name", json.getString("name"));
            map.put("abbr", json.getString("abbr"));
            arraylist.add(map);
```

map will give me all id's all name's and all abbr's
Do i need to store them in List iterate???

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
String response = "{\"students\":[{\"id\":\"26\",\"name\":\"aaa\",\"abbr\":\"A\"},{\"id\":\"27\",\"name\":\"bbb\",\"abbr\":\"B\"},{\"id\":\"28\",\"name\":\"ccc\",\"abbr\":\"C\"}]}}";
try{
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> studentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    JSONObject responeJsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray studentsJsonArry =  responeJsonObject.getJSONArray("students");
    for (int i=0;i<studentsJsonArry.length();i++){
        HashMap<String, String> studentData = new HashMap<String, String>();
        studentData.put("id", studentsJsonArry.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
        studentData.put("name", studentsJsonArry.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
        studentData.put("abbr", studentsJsonArry.getJSONObject(i).getString("abbr"));
        studentList.add(studentData);
    }

    for (HashMap<String,String> student : studentList){
        System.out.print("id"+student.get("id"));
        System.out.print("name"+student.get("name"));
        System.out.print("abbr"+student.get("abbr"));
    }

}catch (Throwable e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** there is a way for you to get in one line and my favorite is the use of the [Gson Libray](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list) which will allow you to parse your string and get a list of object "Students" (List) where you then only need to do :

```
TextView id = (TextView) findViewById(R.Id.textview);
TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.Id.textview);
TextView abbr = (TextView) findViewById(R.Id.textview);

id.setText(student.getId());
name.setText(student.getName());
abbr.setText(student.getAbbr());
```

Where student is an entry in the List

Hope this can help you out with your problem =)

Comment: how to use Gson library?? I am going to store each row value in database table...

Comment: Look, here is an easy tuto about how to use Gson : http://primalpop.wordpress.com/2010/06/05/parsing-json-using-gson-in-android/